# how to add images into UIView

Tags: uiview

I Have 4 images. I want to add images in UIView one by one.
please give me any idea. How to add images array in UIView.

Comment: you want to animate those images ?

Comment: yes I want to animate this image array one by one

Comment: i want to add Ken Burns Effect on each image

Comment: you must set the frame of the imageview  and change the height and width instead of x and y in my code... (answer that i have provided)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not clear from your question but i am guessing you wan to show images in your view one by one after some time delays... If it is what you want you van get it by

```
[self performSelector:@selector(callFunction) withObject:nil afterDelay:0 ];
[self performSelector:@selector(callFunction2) withObject:nil afterDelay:k_AnimateTime ];
[self performSelector:@selector(callFunction3) withObject:nil afterDelay:2*k_AnimateTime ];
```

in the Function

```
imageview = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)]autorelease];
    imageview.image = [[UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithString:name]]autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:imageview];
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(imageview.frame.origin.x, (imageview.frame.origin.y), imageview.frame.size.width, imageview.frame.size.height);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    //[UIView setAnimationWillStartSelector:@selector(Transform2)];


    [UIView setAnimationDuration:k_AnimateTime];

    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    //[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(increaseCount)];
    imageview.frame = CGRectMake(imageview.frame.origin.x - Ex, (imageview.frame.origin.y - Ey), imageview.frame.size.width, imageview.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [self.view addSubview:imageview];

}
```

Comment: how repeat function when all animation complete?

Comment: Remove all images from super view and call the same function again